# Java.io Two ways to obtain buffered character stream from unbuffered byte one

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I am switching to Java from c++ and now going through some of the documentation on Java IO. So if I want to make buffered character stream from unbuffered byte stream, I can do this in two ways:

```
Reader input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Xanadu.txt")));
```

and

```
Reader input2 = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Xanadu.txt")));
```

So I can make it character and after this buffered or vise versa.
What is the difference between them and which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference.  The two versions will behave the same way.

There is a likely to be difference in performance, with the first version likely to be a bit faster than the second version when you read characters from the `Reader` one at a time.

- In the first version, an entire buffer full of data will be converted from bytes to chars in a single operation.  Then each `read()` call on the `Reader` will fetch a character directly from the character buffer.
- In the second version, each `read()` call on the `Reader` performs one or more `read()` calls on the input stream and converts only those bytes read to a character.

---

If I was going to implement this (precise) functionality, I would do it like this:

```
  Reader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Xanadu.txt"));
```

and let `FileReader` deal with the bytes-to-characters decoding under the hood.

There is a case for using an `InputStreamReader`, but only if you need to specify the character set for the bytes-to-characters conversion explicitly.